# iOS Swift issue with UIStoryBoardSegue method

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue, ios8

I'm trying to convert an **Objective-C method to Swift.**

**The Objective-C method is the following:**

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        NSString *string = [feeds[indexPath.row] objectForKey: @"link"];

        string = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@" "];

        [[segue destinationViewController] setUrl:string];
    }
}
```

**The Swift method I got so far (with an issue) is the following:**

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender: AnyObject!)
{
    if (segue.identifier == "showDetail") {

        var indexPath:NSIndexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
        var string:NSString = self.feeds[indexPath.row] as String

        string = string.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n", withString: "")

        segue.destinationViewController.setURL(string, forKey: nil)
    }
}
```

**The main issue is with the last line:**

```
segue.destinationViewController.setURL(string, forKey: nil)
```

I'm getting the following error:

*"Cannot convert the expression's type 'Void' to type 'NSURL!'"*

**This is the controller I'm trying to call:**

```
import UIKit

class DetailViewController: UIViewController
{
    var url:NSString!
    var webView:UIWebView!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var url:NSURL = NSURL(string:self.url.stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding))
        var request:NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
        webView.loadRequest(request)
    }
}
```

I hope someone can help me to figure this out, it's been a while I'm struggling with this. :/

Thanks!

Comment: What's your method signature for `setURL` - can you post the header for that view controller?

Comment: It looks like your setURL method is expecting an NSURL, not a string

Comment: What do you mean with header? Swift doesn't have any header :s

Comment: Is your destinationViewController in Objective-C? If so it'll have a bridging header. Or if it's in Swift, post that.

Comment: I've updated the post with the controller to call by segue.destinationViewController

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct pattern to use when accessing the destinationViewController in Objective C or Swift is to cast it to the correct subclass type. This will then allow you to access the subclasses methods and properties.

So you should say

```
let myDestVC = segue.destinationViewController as MyViewControllerClass
```

Or in Objective C

```
MyViewControllerClass *myDestVC =(MyViewControllerClass *)segue.destinationViewController;
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling `segue.destinationViewController.setURL(string, forKey: nil)`? Where did the `forKey:` part come from? I think you're just calling the wrong method, and the error message is not terribly helpful.